# DENY access to EXEC for a role

Tags: sql-server, permissions, role

I have a read-only database user that I do not want to be able to run the `EXEC` command. I ran the following:

```
DENY EXECUTE to db_USERROLE_deny
```

That completed successfully; however, when I sign in as that user and run the following it runs and gives me output:

```
EXEC sp_columns table1
```

How can I deny this user the ability to run `EXEC` command on the database he connects to?

Answer (score 2):

Since these are system stored procedures, you need to deny permissions in the *master* database using a **new role** in *master*, not the one you already have:

1. Add a new role *DenyExecRole* in master
2. Add the desired login to that role
3. Deny execute permissions:

   ```
   USE master;
   DENY EXECUTE TO DenyExecRole;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it should be something like:

```
USE <database name>;
DENY EXECUTE ON OBJECT::<object name>
    TO user name;
GO
```

Or:

```
DENY EXECUTE TO <user name>
```

Alternatively you can create a *database* role and assign table rights to this role then attach the role to the user:

1. Create a new database role named appropriately

   ```
   USE DatabaseName;
   GO
   CREATE ROLE test;
   GO
   ```
2. Grant *select* permission on the required tables to the new role

   ```
   USE DatabaseName;
   GO
   GRANT SELECT ON dbo.Table1 TO test;
   GRANT SELECT ON dbo.Table2 TO test;
   ... for all tables
   ```
3. Add the users to the role

   ```
   USE DatabaseName;
   GO
   EXEC sys.sp_addrolemember 
       @rolename = N'test',
       @membername = N'DatabaseUserName';
   ```

Comment: I do have a role created, and that is where all my permissions are set.  With your first example, would I need to DENY the EXECUTE on every object name (ex: every sp_command) or can I do a global DENY for all procedures?

Comment: @ProfessionalAmateur: You can simply   deny execute  to 'user'